# Posible to resize app window through animation (keyframes)?

Tags: css, electron

Example: https://codepen.io/CottageCabbage/pen/oNGqLbw

Wanted to know whether this would be possible with Electron? One of the three containers would be the app in this case. Clicking a button, the window size would increase/decrease smoothly as in the example codepen

Managed to make a smaller copy of codepen below, hope it helps

```js
function toggleCard() {
  var a = document.getElementById('B');
  a.classList.add('openB');
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#B {
  width: 0;
}
.openB {
  animation-name: openB;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes openB {
  0% {width: 0}
  100% {width: 200px;}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='A' class='card' style='background: green;'>
    <h1 onclick='toggleCard()'>Toggle<h1>
  </div>
  <div id='B' class='card' style='background: red;'>
  
  </div>
</div>
```